# Images now showing within NavigationView/NagivationLink

Tags: swiftui

I was trying to show multiple clickable images within NavigationView/NagivationLink container(s).

```
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            ForEach(self.sets) { set in
                NavigationLink(destination: ExerciseVideoView(items: set.items )) {
                    Image("group-\(set.purpose)")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(height: 300, alignment: .leading)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the images are not shown.

When i remove NavigationView & NagivationLink lines - everything goes well, apart from making the images clickable of course. Here's how the screen looks like when images are shown:

[image]

and this is what happens when i uncomment NavigationView & NagivationLink lines:

[image]

Could you please explain me why are not they shown when i use NagivationLink?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NavigationLink` interprets images by default as *template* rendering mode, so you have to specify explicitly

```
NavigationLink(destination: ExerciseVideoView(items: set.items )) {
    Image("group-\(set.purpose)")
        .resizable()
        .renderingMode(.original)                 // << here !!
        .frame(height: 300, alignment: .leading)
}
```

Comment: Hey man! Thank you for your help, it works now.

But i got another problem - when i add "Color.blue" view between the images it doesn't appear. Seems like it's not there. May be there is something i should add to Color to make it visible too?